# error using ByVal VBA

Tags: vba, byval

In some computers I get errors when I use byVal modifier. I had in my code some of them but I manage to remove all of them but I need it in the following code:

```
Public Declare Function GetDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function ReleaseDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
  ByVal hdc As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function GetDeviceCaps Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As Long, _
  ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long

Const HWND_DESKTOP As Long = 0
Const LOGPIXELSX As Long = 88
Const LOGPIXELSY As Long = 90

'--------------------------------------------------
Public Function TwipsPerPixelX() As Single
'--------------------------------------------------
'Returns the width of a pixel, in twips.
'--------------------------------------------------
  Dim lngDC As Long
  lngDC = GetDC(HWND_DESKTOP)
  TwipsPerPixelX = 1440& / GetDeviceCaps(lngDC, LOGPIXELSX)
  ReleaseDC HWND_DESKTOP, lngDC
End Function

'--------------------------------------------------
Public Function TwipsPerPixelY() As Single
'--------------------------------------------------
'Returns the height of a pixel, in twips.
'--------------------------------------------------
  Dim lngDC As Long
  lngDC = GetDC(HWND_DESKTOP)
  TwipsPerPixelY = 1440& / GetDeviceCaps(lngDC, LOGPIXELSY)
  ReleaseDC HWND_DESKTOP, lngDC
End Function
```

I am sure that the error is because of ByVal. I was using ByVal in more functions and they were not working but when I do it in another way (not using ByVal) they work and if I just delete this functions all the others works perfectly. I cannot understand the reason.

Another weird thing is that it happens only in some computers (Win8, office 2013). But I have the same OS, office and security settings. The error that it gives is compilation error:

"compilation error in hidden module: Module4"

Comment: What does your code do, (or what is it supposed to do)?

Comment: What is the exact error message ?

Comment: When calling Windows API functions, you don't really have a choice -  if it is expecting a ByRef (that is, a pointer to data in dynamic memory), then you must declare it that way (unless you directly provide the pointer as a ByVal long).  If it is expecting a ByVal parameter (that is, a value type such as an array or double or integer etc copied onto the stack as a parameter for the function), then you must declare it that way.  As Alexandre asked, what is the error you get?

Comment: The error that I get is compilation error in hidden module: Module4 and in the Module4 I have the code I post there. But before I have ByVal in more places and it was giving errors in them as well. Removing the ByVal fix the problem but as Blackhawk says calling Windows API functions I have not other choice.

Comment: Do you have 64-bit versions of Office?

Comment: Yes I do. At least in one that is failing has 64 bit office. I have 32 bit and in mine is working.

Comment: well, see if [**`this`**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19723528/whats-the-meaning-of-in-vb6-0-function-parameter/19724286#19724286) helps you understand a bit more

Comment: It was interesting... But I don't understand how this can affect to my code. You think that if I put lngDC = GetDC(HWND_DESKTOP&) instead of lngDC = GetDC(HWND_DESKTOP) and so on it won't fail? And why it is working now in 32 bit version and not in 64 bit version? Because in my computer (Win8 64 bit, office 2013 32 bit) it is working and the same code in other computer (Win8 64 bit, office 2013 64 bit) is not working. I need a bit more of light to see it :)

Comment: I finally have access to the computer that was giving me the error and it is still failing using & in the variables.